# How to get users that purchased items ONLY in a specific time period (MySQL Database)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains all purchased items.

I need to check which users purchased items in a specific period of time (say between 2013-03-21 to 2013-04-21) and never purchased anything after that.

I can select users that purchased items in that period of time, but I don't know how to filter those users that never purchased anything after that...

```
SELECT `userId`, `email` FROM my_table 
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-03-21' AND '2013-04-21' GROUP BY `userId`
```

Comment: What table are your purchases stored in? Can you show the structure of it?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN later purchases on to that query. Those with NULL values will be the answer. Also, in the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of GROUP BY is inappropriate. Perhaps you meant to use the DISTINCT operator.

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for tip, i was not aware of DISTINCT operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give this a try

```
SELECT 
  user_id
FROM 
  my_table 
WHERE 
  purchase_date >= '2012-05-01'        --your_start_date
GROUP BY 
  user_id
HAVING 
  max(purchase_date) <= '2012-06-01';  --your_end_date
```

It works by getting all the records `>= start date`, groups the resultset by `user_id` and then finds the `max` purchase date for every user. The `max` purchase date should be `<=end date`. Since this query does not use a `join/inner query` it could be faster

**Test data**

```
CREATE table user_purchases(user_id int, purchase_date date);
insert into user_purchases values (1, '2012-05-01');
insert into user_purchases values (2, '2012-05-06');
insert into user_purchases values (3, '2012-05-20');
insert into user_purchases values (4, '2012-06-01');
insert into user_purchases values (4, '2012-09-06');
insert into user_purchases values (1, '2012-09-06');
```

**Output**

```
| USER_ID |
-----------
|       2 |
|       3 |
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6eb38/3)

Comment: can you please explain this query ? (i'm confused with `max()` function.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a standard way to accomplish that:

```
SELECT `userId`, `email` FROM my_table mt
WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-03-21' AND '2013-04-21' 
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM my_table mt2 WHERE 
        mt2.`userId` = mt.`userId` 
        and mt2.`date` > '2013-04-21' 
)
GROUP BY `userId`
```

Comment: my table has over 440,000 records and this query takes too long to execute (more than 20 minutes !!!!, tested on both remote and local database), is it because of query not being optimized or its normal to take that much time ?!

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do it in two stages - one query to get the list of users who did buy within the time period, then another query to take that list of users and see if they bought anything afterwards, e.g.

```
SELECT userID, email, count(after.*) AS purchases
FROM my_table AS after
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT userID
    FROM my_table
    WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-03-21' AND '2013-04-21'
) AS during ON after.userID = during.userID
WHERE after.date > '2013-04-21'
HAVING purchases = 0;
```

Inner query gets the list of userIDs who purchased at least one thing during that period. That list is then joined back against the same table, but filtered for purchases AFTER the period , and counts how many purchases they made and filters down to only those users with 0 "after" purchases.

probably won't work as written - haven't had my morning tea yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
 SELECT `userId`, `email` 
 FROM my_table WHERE `date` BETWEEN '2013-03-21' AND '2013-04-21' 
 and user_id not in 
    (select user_id from my_table 
     where `date` < '2013-03-21' or `date` > '2013-04-21' ) 
 GROUP BY `userId`
```

Comment: this query (just like initial query that i wrote and is similar to yours) takes too long to execute (database has over 440,000 record, takes over 20 minutes to execute), why is that ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT `userId`, `email` FROM my_table WHERE (`date` BETWEEN '2013-03-21' AND '2013-04-21') and `date` >= '2013-04-21'  GROUP BY `userId`
```

This will select only the users who purchased during that timeframe **AND** purchased after that timeframe.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    a.userId,
    a.email 
FROM
    my_table AS a 
WHERE a.date BETWEEN '2013-03-21' 
    AND '2013-04-21' 
    AND a.userId NOT IN 
    (SELECT 
        b.userId
    FROM
        my_table AS b 
    WHERE b.date BETWEEN '2013-04-22' 
        AND CURDATE() 
    GROUP BY b.userId) 
GROUP BY a.userId
```

This filters out anyone who has not purchased anything from the end date to the present.